# How do I display the UID of member in Drupal (Commons)?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commons

I am trying to add a record in a table based upon the UID of a member in my Drupal site. I am doing this with a form that is on each member's page. For this to work properly, I need to use the UID in the mysql query. This is being included in the page with a  in a Drupal block.

If I use $uid = $user->uid;, it will be my UID as admin. I need for it to populate with the UID of of the member whose page I am currently viewing.

Here's a little snippet of my code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO profile_values (fid, uid, value) VALUES ('99','$uid', '$newcompany')");
```

I need to define $uid  and this will work perfectly! (this is Drupal Commons, if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a user page then whatever the current URL is the underlying router path will be `user/%`, where `%` is the user's ID.

With this in mind you can use Drupal's [`arg()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) to grab the parts of the URL split by the `/` character, and thus the user ID:

```
// This if statement just checks that you're on a user page.
if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1)) {
  $uid = arg(1);
}
```

Bear in mind the `if` above will also match paths such as `user/%/edit` so if that's going to cause a problem just add `&& is_null(arg(2))` to the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I haven't tried your example yet, but I thought of something similar that worked (although it may not be the best way to do it?).

I did this:
`//get user id from url
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$array = explode("/",$url);
$uid = $array[3];`

because the url is tld/directory-of-drupal-site/user/uid/edit

Comment: It's probably safer to use the `arg()` function in case you enable URL aliases later on...it would stop working with that code. Otherwise though that's pretty much exactly what the `arg()` function does, but using `$_GET['q']` instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` :)